# About Microsoft CDN server on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10, store, microsoft-cdn

I will attempt to be clear.  Well, in the old web store of Windows Phone 8 before I could download manually any app or game, via the link: "Download and install manually" as you can see
[in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiAtP.png) It is a feature that was lost with the arrival of the new store of Windows 10.

Ok. Now, in the following video [Download and Install Apps (XAP/APPX Files) on WP8.1 via PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dyLZuHdaj8) you can see at time t=53 sec, appears at bottom of page the link `http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/vimeo/the App ID/xap?apptype=regular`

After the user clicks on 'Download and install manually' a popup box appears. Now you can see inside the pop-up box that the downloading of the app is downloaded from: `http://cdn.marketplacecontent.windowsphone.com`

But in fact the complete address follows this format:

```
http://cdn.marketplacecontent.windowsphone.com/public/the App ID?downloadname=name of the app.type of file(xap, appx or appxbundle)
```

For example, this is the direction of the game Tentacles: Enter the Mind from the Microsoft CDN server:

```
http://cdn.marketplacecontent.windowsphone.com/public/8915ee7c-c55d-4e8f-a0b6-f80497e6f26e?downloadname=tentacles-enter-the-mind.xap
```

As you just seen, the old web store of Windows Phone 8 could download apps and games from the Microsoft CDN server. Even with the new store Windows 10 you can still download apps from Microsoft CDN. There are website that somehow can download apps and games from the Microsoft CDN server such as: www.appx4fun.com www.windowscommunity.in and www.winphonehub.org to mention some.

Based upon everything I said, you have any idea of how to I can access the Microsoft CDN server to download apps without resorting to third-party stores? I would like to know how they do it.

**NOTE:** All apps can be downloaded manually using this address:`http://cdn.marketplacecontent.windowsphone.com/public/the App ID?downloadname=name of the app.type of file(xap, appx or appxbundle)`but for it to work you need to know the ID of the app you want to download and the type of file. How can I find the ID of the app? Know the ID is a very important information!

Well, that's all. I hope your answer
Regards.

Comment: so your question is how to get the app id?

Comment: @SeeSharp Hi, Thanks for replying. It is right, but I also want to know how I can access the Microsoft CDN server to download apps. You know anything about this? You can help me?

Comment: There's a tool at https://wpsnitch.appspot.com/ which may help you get the app id.